# Flink rocksdb per slot memory configuration issue

Tags: apache-flink

I have 32GB of managed memory and 8 task slots.
As `state.backend.rocksdb.memory.managed` is set to true, each rockdb  in each task slot uses 4GB of memory.
Some of my tasks do not require a rocksdb backend so I want to increase this 4GB to 6GB by setting `state.backend.rocksdb.memory.fixed-per-slot: 6000m`

The problem when I set `state.backend.rocksdb.memory.fixed-per-slot: 6000m` is on Flink UI, in task manager page, I cant see the allocated managed memory anymore.

As you can see when `state.backend.rocksdb.memory.fixed-per-slot` is not set and `state.backend.rocksdb.memory.managed: true`, 4GB usage appears on managed memory for each running task which uses rocksdb backend.

[image]

But after setting `state.backend.rocksdb.memory.fixed-per-slot: 6000m` , Managed Memory always shows zero!

1- How can I watch the managed memory allocation after setting `state.backend.rocksdb.memory.fixed-per-slot: 6000m`

2- Should `state.backend.rocksdb.memory.managed` be set to  true even I set fixed-per-slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another reply we got from the hive:
"Fixed-per-slot overrides managed memory setting, so managed zero is expected  (it's either fixed-per-slot or managed). As Yuval wrote you can see the memory instances by checking the LRU caches.
One more thing to check is write_buffer_manager pointer in the RocksDB log file. It will be different for each operator if neither fixed-per-slot or managed memory is used and shared between instances otherwise"

Let us know if this is useful

Comment: thanks. this was the answer I was looking for. by the way what "shared between instances otherwise" means? can we share memory between instances for rocksdb?

Comment: Great, glad we could help. As per your follow-up questions, see below:
Yes, that's what managed memory and fixed-per-slot do. When neither is specified, each Rocksdb database will have its own LRUCache and write buffer manager. If you specify managed memory, RocksDB will have shared LRUCache and write buffer manager for all databases in a  taskmanager.  In the case of fixed-per-slot, all RocksDB databases in each slot will have shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

Shared your question with the Speedb hive on Discord and here's the "honey" we got for you:

We don't have much experience with Flink setups regarding how to configure the memory limits and their different parameters. However, RocksDB uses a shared Block Cache to control the memory limits of your state. so for question 1 - you could grep "block_cache:" and "capacity :" from all the LOG files of all the DBs (operators). the total memory limit allocated to RocksDB through the block cache would be the sum of the capacity for all the unique pointers. the same block cache (memory) can be shared across DBs.
do note that RocksDB might use more memory than the block cache capacity.

Hope this help. If you have follow-up questions or want more help with this, send us a message on [Discord](https://discord.gg/5fVUUtM2cG).